# Qt Static Building Error on Installation with command "nmake install" or "jom install"

Tags: qt, static, visual-studio-2015, nmake

I try to build a static and different version of Qt(5.7) from the Source Code beside another installed version from binary package (5.6.1). I have been thoroughly following this [tutorial building qt static library](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2015/07/03/how-to-build-qt-5-5-static-libraries-using-any-microsoft-visual-c-compiler/) changing the "jom" command to "nmake" (I read somewhere that jom just make the build quicker),after successfully building with "jom" command (or "nmake", both command shows no error), I finally stuck at the last step "jom install", or in this instance "nmake install". When I inputted the command, I get this error:

```
    C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.7\qt-5.7.0>nmake install

    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cd qtbase\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.7\qt-5.7.0\qtbase\
    bin\qmake C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.7\qt-5.7.0\qtbase\qtbase.pro -o Makefile ) &&         
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile install

    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cd src\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.7\qt-5.7.0\qtbase\bin\qmake C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.7\qt-5.7.0\qtbase\src\src.pro -o 
    Makefile) && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile install


    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    cd corelib\ && ( if not exist Makefile.qtzlib C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.7\qt-5.7.0
    \qtbase\bin\qmake C:\Qt\Qt5.6.1\5.7\qt-5.7.0\qtbase\src\corelib\qtzlib.pro -o Ma
    kefile.qtzlib ) && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\n
    make.exe" -f Makefile.qtzlib install

    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.qtzlib.Debug install

    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'if' : return code '0x1'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
    \VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
    Stop.
```

I tried rebuilding the source code with both jom and nmake, reducing the environment variables path of the nmake to C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin, compiling all the modules one by one, still cannot do the "nmake install" or "jom install" command. Any ideas what went wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

In my case I set an unexists disk to -prefix argument of the confiture command, which cause this same error with yours.

I just simply replace all the F:(not exists) to E:(my qt is under this disk) in all Makefile and Makefile.* files, then nmake install works normally.

Hope this helps.